# How do you remove an HTML code that is on multiple webpages at once in WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress, web

How do you remove an html code that is on multiple webpages at once?

I have a HTML code that used to be useful, but now it is only causing trouble. Is there a way to delete the code at once throughout the site?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but you have to delete them by opening your template(s), where the code is.

If it's a line in footer.php then a single operation. But if it's something in multiple page templates then open each one and delete.

Anway, PHP frameworks generally use single element in multiple places of user generated content. So, I assume it will be manually doable.

Comment: thanks for the info. I think it's best to manually delete them at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the posts in the database then there is a way to do it, but I highly recommend, that you need to backup the database before doing this. Very Important.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '<h1>Title</h1>','');
```

You can then run the above sql on the database, which will remove that h1 tag if that was what you want to remove.
Hope that helps.

Remember - Backup First before doing any direct changes on the database.

Comment: Sadly they aren't just checked, guess I will manually go through a couple hundred pages to remove them. thanks anyway

Comment: sorry i had an error in the field that was there. try the one above

Comment: of course change the tag you are replacing from <h1>Title</h1> to what you are removing